# How to transfer button sender to another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

So I am building a simple messenger in swift. I am using a view state enum for different UIs upon `viewWillAppear` i.e .Offline, .Default. I have a `convoVC` and an `InboxVC`

From my `InboxVC`, I am transitioning to a `convoVC` which displays messages between the user and another user that is either selected from the inbox (in which case I want .Default state for `conversationVC`), or selected from a query using a searchbar when I transition from a "compose new message" button (in which case I want ".Compose" state for `conversationVC`).

I am having trouble setting the state on `convoVC` given the sender of my function which calls the segue from `InboxVC` to `convoVC`

> sender of type UIBarbuttonItem if the compose button is pressed to make the transition, or sender of type myAppName.InboxVC if tableview cell is pressed to make the transition.

Code for what happens in each state is trivial, for lack of a better word.

This is my action function in `InboxVC` called from either my tableView's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath method`, or from `barButtonItem` selector:

```
func compose(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toConversation", sender: sender)
}
```

I have tried capturing sender (within compose function, and within `ViewWillDisappear` but not both) in a variable declared within `InboxVC` and transferring it to another variable in `convoVC` to then check its type to set state in `convoVC`.

My problem is that it always comes out to nil. How do I transfer the sender? pls help I am new to swift.
Thanks! (tagged obj-c because translating is not hard)

the variable is called sender in both VCs and is declared as type AnyObject?

I tried

```
self.sender = sender
convoVC().sender = sender
```

I also tried

```
self.sender = sender
```

and then setting `sender (in convoVC) = InboxVC().sender`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func compose(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toConversation", sender: sender)
}
```

Here in `compose(sender: AnyObject)` sender is your button object and in `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toConversation", sender: sender)` sender is your view controller.

So you have to call `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toConversation", sender: self)` with `self`.

And to pass button object you can create a reference in your another class and in  `func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)`  method you should create object of that class and assign you button sender.

Comment: Not quite. In compose, my sender will be either my view controller, or my bar button item depending on whether user taps on view controller tableview cell, or user taps on bar button item. So I have to keep sender: sender in my call to the performSegueWithIdentifier method. Other than that, you were right. I was thinking about this completely differently, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

func compose(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toConversation", sender: sender)
}

Here in 
compose(sender: AnyObject)
sender is your button object 
and in 
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toConversation", sender: sender)
sender is your view controller.

So you havre to call
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toConversation", sender: self) with self.

And to pass button object you can create a reference in your another class and in  func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)  method you should create object of that class and assign you button sender.